# Is there a way to ensure page redirection works on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a small application running on Net core 3.1 (C#) that fails to redirect to a page when the app is published on IIS.
However upon running on Visual Studio, it works perfectly fine. I have checked the IIS logs and it gets the POST action.
Web inspection tools return a 404.

My Index View to be accessed first is as follows:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
```

The controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(OTPData mydata)
{
  .
  .
return RedirectToAction("EnterOTP")
}
```

When debugging to the attached process, the following window pops up:

[image]

Comment: 404 means page not found. Are you running your website inside the application/virtual Directory? Example: website/example.
Can you edit your post and add ```EnterOTP``` method?

Comment: @MatheusDasuke It's not within a virtual directory. I have it published to a folder within wwwroot

Comment: Is ```EnterOTP```  on the same controller?

Comment: Open dev tools in Chrome/Firefox (F12), hit that preserve log, and retry your operation. You should be able to see all the activity

Comment: @MatheusDasuke Yes, It is within the same controller

Comment: Does the URL in your browser search bar change?

Comment: @Sekhar The logs still return a 404, basically the site doesn't redirect. However, debugging on Visual studio successfully redirects the page

Comment: @Sekhar I just attached a process and performed a "step over" over the code. On the `RedirectToAction` I get a modal window with the following link [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/7e8bbb70b266b2fdaf0b11ec47fb3077761fb6bf/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ControllerActionInvoker.cs]

Comment: @Nickson just change something like that ```return RedirectToAction("YourActionName", "YourControllerName");```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use tracing to **troubleshoot failed requests**.

1. You can **enable "Failed Request Tracking"**.
2. When a 404 error occurs, open the **log file** to view detailed error information, such as the requested URL.
3. **[Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)**
4. You can find the place of error according to the detailed error prompt. You can also tell us the specific error message, and we can give you some suggestions or solutions based on it.